# How to get count from distinct value one column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id     2      3

1,   14406,  2189
2,   14428,  2191,
3,   14442,  2192,
4,   14441,  2192,
5,   14441,  2192,
```

And I wonder how if it's possible to get count so I can tell how many times string where 2nd column and 3rd column are the same appears. I see that 1st string is unique so it appears 1 time. The same with 2. In the third string 2 column is unique so it means this row is unique too. But 4th and 5th string are the same and I want to display that it appears 2 times in my table. How could I count it? Should I use Group by or something like subqueries?

Comment: if possible, add your expected output. even better, add any attempted solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'd **group by** col 2 and 3, so as to get one record for each distinct pair. For each pair you want all IDs involved, so build a string of IDs with **GROUP_CONCAT**. Then only keep pairs that occur more than once using the **HAVING** clause.

```
select col2, col3, group_concat(id) as ids
from mytable
group by col2, col3
having count(*) > 1;
```

```
col2   col3   ids  
14441  2192   4,5
```

(This is essentially splash58's answer, so you can accept that. I just thought it would be good to explain the steps involved.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
select `2`, `3`, count(*)
from (select distinct `2`, `3` from your_table) as a
group by `2`, `3`
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(id) as count_times
FROM table 
WHERE column1=column2
```

Comment: Mb you got me wrong. I didn't mean they should be equal to each other. I wanted to say: How to show how many times does string with the same 2nd and 3rd appears. Not when 2 and 3 string are equal but when there's another string with the same 2nd and 3rd fields

Answer (score 0):

```
select group_concat(id), count(*) c 
    from thetable 
  group by `2`, `3` 
  having c > 1
```

result

```
group_concat(id)    c
4,5                 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 2,count(*)
from my_table
group by
2
```

Comment: Maybe I do something wrong but it tells me : `SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: While this question may answer the question, adding a description about why it works will improve it's long-term value.